# Set iFrame width and height based on content

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, height, width

Currently I have a jquery iframe modal dialog which opens an ASPX page. This page contains another iFrame with jQuery.  The content iframe does not have any height or width set and so is sizing as per the size of content inside.  The outer jQuery iframe modal does not size according to the content iframe within it.
Here is the code to open the modal:

```
function openModal() {

    var horizontalPadding = 30;
    var verticalPadding = 30;
    var jqurl = "ContentPage.aspx";
    var title = "Modal Title";
    jQuery('<iframe scrolling="no" id="cLaunch" class="cLaunch" src="' + jqurl + '" frameborder="0"/>').dialog({
        title: title,
        modal: true,
        resizable: true,
        position: ['center', 50],

        fluid:true,
        overlay: {
            opacity: 0.5,
            background: "grey"
        }

    });
}

setInterval(function () {
    document.getElementById("cLaunch").style.width = document.getElementById("cLaunch").contentWindow.document.documentElement.scrollWidth + 30 +  'px';
    document.getElementById("cLaunch").style.height = document.getElementById("cLaunch").contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';


}, 1000)
```

ConentPage.aspx:

```
<iframe name="contentloader"  id="contentloader"  frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to set the width and height of the iframe , based on the content loaded inside the iframe

```
$("#cLaunch").load(function() {
    $(this).height( $(this).contents().find("body").height());
    $(this).width( $(this).contents().find("body").width());
});
```